Taking partial derivatives of regression models
For a general statistical model with function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, the partial effect of $x_1$ is what we get when we take the partial derivative while holding $x_2$ and $x_3$ fixed at specific values (e.g. $c_1, c_2$):
$$ \text{Partial Effect of } x_1 = \frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\partial x_1}\bigg|_{x_2=c_2, x_3=c_3} $$
The marginal effect, on the other hand, involves taking an expectation over the distribution of the other variables (where we have $n$ data points and $x_{2i}$ and $x_{3i}$ are the observed values in our dataset):
$$ \text{Marginal Effect of } x_1 = E_{x_2,x_3}\left[\frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\partial x_1}\right] $$
$$ \text{Estimated Marginal Effect of } x_1 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(x_1, x_{2i}, x_{3i})}{\partial x_1} $$
I have a question about the following point: For non-linear statistical models, when considering the effects over large differences, do we have to adapt the calculus?
For example, for a small change $\Delta x$ around point $x$, the local approximation using the derivative is (for variable $X_1$, holding other variables as constant):
$$ \text{Effect}_{\text{}}(\Delta x) \approx \frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\partial x_1}\Delta x $$
I don't think the same logic fully applies for larger value of $\Delta x$, as the slopes at each point of this range will now be different:
$$ \text{Effect}_{\text{}}(\Delta x) = \int_{x}^{x + \Delta x} \frac{\partial f(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\partial x_1} dx_1 $$
Is this correct? For non-linear models, the derivatives needed for effect size calculations need be modified accordingly to reflect the approximation related issues?

A note on calculus : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5010389/derivatives-of-linear-functions-vs-derivatives-of-non-linear-functions


this isn't what you were asking about, but you may nevertheless be interested in the Integrated Gradient method from deep learning https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01365
